Proving the inequality involving exponentials and factorials
Question
Show that for any $\lambda \geq 1$,
$$\dfrac{\lambda ^{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor}}{(e^\lambda -1)\, \lfloor \lambda \rfloor!}> \dfrac{\lambda' ^{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor}}{e^{\lambda'}\, \lfloor \lambda' \rfloor!},$$
where $\lambda' = \lambda \frac{e^\lambda}{e^\lambda-1}$.

After rearranging terms, the desired inequality becomes,
$$\dfrac{e^\lambda -1}{e^{\lambda'}} \cdot \dfrac{\lambda' ^{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor}}{\lambda ^{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor}} \cdot \dfrac{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor!}{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor!} < 1$$
Notice that $\lambda<\lambda'< (1+ \frac{1}{e-1})\lambda$ (which I think would be helpful at some point). So,  $\dfrac{e^\lambda -1}{e^{\lambda'}}<1$. If I can show that $\dfrac{\lambda' ^{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor}}{\lambda ^{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor}} \cdot \dfrac{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor!}{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor!} < 1$, I would be done.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?

As you said, it suffices to show that $$a=\dfrac{e^\lambda -1}{e^{\lambda'}} \cdot \dfrac{\lambda' ^{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor}}{\lambda ^{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor}} \cdot \dfrac{\lfloor \lambda \rfloor!}{\lfloor \lambda' \rfloor!} < 1.$$
Consider the function $f(x)=\frac{e^x\cdot \lfloor x\rfloor!}{x^{\lfloor x\rfloor}}$. We have $a<\frac{f(\lambda)}{f(\lambda')}$. $f$ is a positive function, so if we can show that it's increasing, we'd be done (since $\lambda'>\lambda$).
In the interval $[n,n+1)$ for integer $n$, $f(x)$ is smooth. Specifically, it would look like $\frac{e^x\cdot n!}{x^n}$. The derivative of this is $$\frac{e^xn!}{x^{n+1}}(x-n).$$ This is $0$ at $x=n$ and positive for $n<x<n+1$, so $f(x)$ is strictly increasing in this interval. Note that this holds for all integer $n$.
It remains to show that $f(x)$ is continuous, since we could have "jumps" at the integer $n$. For this, note that the left-hand limit at $x=n$ is $e^n\frac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}$ while the right-hand limit is $e^n\frac{n!}{n^n}$. But these are equal, so we're done.
